# Drupal 8 Search Bug

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I have a problem with the Search API on Drupal 8.7.14; the site is in Hebrew.

When I try to search for more than one word, I get no results. If I search for only one word, all results that contain that word appear. The search view is already configured with a full search filter criterion.

Do you have any ideas?

https://www.screencast.com/t/Pv6jC1X6n

(8.x-1.8 search API version)

Comment: Please use the editor's add-image facility. That makes sure that the image will not get lost if for some reason the link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using the wrong operator for this filter, use **"contains any of these words"**, like on screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nB1k.png

Comment: Thank you but i am using this operator already. https://www.screencast.com/t/X4a5duR7Kf

Comment: What about parse mode? Do you use "single phrase" or "multiple words"?